# Why doesn't this query run?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this query that isn't finishing (I think the server runs out of memory)

```
SELECT fOpen.*, fClose.*
FROM (
    SELECT of.*
    FROM fixtures of
        JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(id) id
            FROM fixtures
            GROUP BY matchId, period, type
        ) ofi ON ofi.id = of.id
) fOpen
JOIN (
    SELECT cf.*
    FROM fixtures cf
        JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(id) id
            FROM fixtures
            GROUP BY matchId, period, type
        ) cfi ON cfi.id = cf.id
) fClose ON fClose.matchId = fOpen.matchId AND fClose.period = fOpen.period AND fClose.type = fOpen.type
```

This is the EXPLAIN of it:

[image]

Those 2 subqueries 'of' and 'cf' take about 1.5s to run, if I run them separately.

'id' is a PRIMARY INDEX and there is a BTREE INDEX named 'matchPeriodType' that has those 3 columns in that order.

More info: MySQL 5.5, 512MB of server memory, and the table has about 400k records.

Comment: No sure, but `of` is a reserved word. It probably doesn't matter, because MySQL will know it's identifier due to the context it is used in, but it's a good practice in general to not use reserved words as aliases.

Comment: It could be memory. 512MB is very little for a server.

Comment: There is no problem with the `of` keyword, but I see your point, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to rewrite your query, so that it is easier to read and should be able to use your indexes. Hope I got it right, could not test without your data.

```
SELECT fOpen.*, fClose.*
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
  FROM fixtures
  GROUP BY matchId, period, type
) ids
JOIN fixtures fOpen  ON ( fOpen.id  = ids.min_id )
JOIN fixtures fClose ON ( fClose.id = ids.max_id );
```

This one gets `MIN(id)` and `MAX(id)` per `matchId`, `period`, `type` (should use your index) and joins the corresponding rows afterwards.

Appending `id` to your existing index `matchPeriodType` could also help, since the sub-query could then be executed with this index only.

Comment: This works, but I'm just sad it doesn't use my 'match, period, type' index for the group by, and when I force index it gets slower, lol

Comment: But `id` is primary and I already have some indexes on the table. Let me show you: http://puu.sh/1e0bJ

Comment: Did you try the extended index I suggested?

Comment: I did and `EXPLAIN` tells me it is using it, but there is no speed difference. At least not with these records. I'll keep it anyway. Thanks for the suggestion. (:

Comment: Working on Peters code, I am wondering if the subselect is not bringing back any key info. Possibly bring matchId, period, type back from the subselect as well (generally a good idea to have the group by fields in the select anyway), then join on those as well as ID

Comment: Well, both the `min_id` and `max_id` are from the same fixture, but for the first and last record of it, so it shouldn't be an issue. Or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, wondering if mysql is not treating the returned ids as indexed fields, while the other 3 fields would be passed back without manipulation and should still be treated as indexes.

Comment: They are passed back without manipulation from what I've tested. (;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how unique the matchid / period / type is. If unique you are joining 400k records against 400k records, possibly with the indexes being lost.

However it appears that the 2 main subselects might be unnecessary. You could just join fixtures against itself and that against the subselects to get the min and max.